# How to print Field with "print when expression" in jasper report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am using jasper studio and I have Field called PAYMENT and TOTAL. PAYMENT is string type which contains values like Cash, Card, Cash Refund and Card Refund.

I am using "print when expression" with TOTAL  field like "$F{PAYMENT}.equals( "cashrefund" ) ? true : false".

When a condition is true I am getting value, but if the condition is false, it includes a blank record in the report. How can I avoid printing blank record in the report? Is it possible if TOTAL prints only where there is any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set print when expression property to `$F{PAYMENT}.equals("cashrefund")` and set remove line when blank property is true `(isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true")`